# Issue with Updating Items in SwiftUI VStack Using Timer Publisher

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm encountering difficulty updating items within a `VStack` in my `SwiftUI` app. Each item (`ListItemView()`) displays a label showing the remaining time. I'm struggling to find an approach to achieve this for each item in a `VStack` (specifically a `LazyVStack`) on the screen.

Here's how my ViewModel is structured:

```
@MainActor
final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    private (set) var models: [MyModel] = []
    @Published private(set) var listItemModels: [MyListItemModel] = []
    
    init() {
        
        Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.updateModelsTimeLeft()
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
        
    }
   
    func fetchData(limit: Int) async {
        do {
            let models = try await APIService.fetchModels()
            self.models = models
            
            listItemModels = models.map { MyListItemModel(id: $0.id,
                                                               timeInMs: $0.timeInMs)}
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching models: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


private extension MyViewModel {
    
    func updateModelsTimeLeft() {
        
        for index in 0..<self.listItemModels.count {
             self.listItemModels[index].timeInMs = // changed based on some logic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MyListItemModel used in the ViewModel is defined as follows:

```
struct MyListItemModel: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var timeInMs: Int
}
```

I'm attempting to display these items on the screen using:

```
LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
    ForEach(viewModel.listItemModels, id: \.id) { model in
        ListItemView(model: model)
    }
}
```

Inside the ListItemView, I'm simply printing the value inside a Text() view.

The problem happens with `Timer` publisher I guess: the UI doesn't update at all.

Any suggestions on how to properly update the UI in SwiftUI when using Timer publisher for this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Not sure how this can be important, but this is how I fetch data:

```
// This is on my main screen's view.
.onAppear {
            Task {
                await viewModel.fetchData(limit: 20)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ugh :) Actually it works. I was updating labels with a same value.

Comment: Anyway, what I figured out.. I that this method makes scrolling a bit choppy. So, if anybody has a suggestion what is a right way to do it, I would appreciate to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch data it's like this:

```
struct Fetcher {

    // in Swift, funcs should always return a result or throw
    func fetchData(limit: Int) async throws -> [Model] {
        return try await APIService.fetchModels() // normally you wouldn't use another object     
    }
}
```

```
@State var models: [MyModel] = []
...
.task {
    let fetcher = Fetcher() // good idea to make this an @Environment so can be swapped out for Previews
    do {
        models = await fetcher.fetchData(limit: 20)
    }
    catch {
        // normally this error would be saved in a @State and shown in a Text
        print("Error fetching models: \(error)")
    }
}
```

`.task` removes the need for a `@StateObject` to manage the lifetime of the async work.

To transform models into certain Views use a computed property like this:

```
var listItemModels: [MyListItemModel] {
    models.map { model in
        MyListItemModel(id: model.id, timeInMs: model.timeInMs) 
    }
}
...
MyList(listItemModels: listItemModels)
```

I'll think about your timer, maybe another `.task` with a while loop with `Task.sleep`.

Comment: Yeah, `.task` part solved choppiness. Thanks a bunch. It pointed me to look at redraws of my main view's body. So I looked in Instruments and I noticed a lot of redraws. Then I used your method with `.task`. I did waiting delay with while loop and `Task.sleep()`.. And it worked. Though, that `while true + sleep(1)` looked scary, so I did recursive method call with `async await`. Both worked fine, and list was scrolling nicely while having countdown timer ticking every second in each list item. Thanks once again!